# Can I sysprep a Windows 7 VHD without any virtualization technology?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc, vhd

I booted from a VHD on my laptop and hoped to sysprep this image, but it didn't let me do it. I got a fatal error during the process. I used the following command: sysprep /generalize /shutdown. My question is it possible at all to sysprep a VHD without any HyperV or virtual PC technology?

Comment: Have you got the correct Windows 7 version of Sysprep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 actually supports booting from VHD without Hyper-V or Virtual PC:
[MSDN Windows 7 VHD Boot Setup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/knom/windows-7-vhd-boot-setup-guideline)

I have been dealing with possibly a similar issue with sysprep under several environments with Real PC's and Virtuals on VMware ESX / vSphere. What I have found is that a single image can go through sysprep 3 times before Windows goes into an "armed" state due to activation protection.

Microsoft has an article discussing the issue and I have used the solution of adding a "disarm" portion to the unattend.xml file and I no longer receive the error message.

[Microsoft Sysprep /generalize Fatal Error](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/error-occurs-when-running-sysprep-generalize)